# Suddenly, when grabbing I can only move objects in increments

Tags: transforms

- I don't know how it happened
- I could only grab an object and move it in increments, as if I was holding "control"
- Only grab/move/translate is affected, the other transformations like rotate and scale are normal.
- If I hold control while grabbing, it'll inverse it and allow me to grab normally and smoothly.
- Only the blender file I was in is affected, if I open other .blend files the problem won't be there.

Does anyone know how this happened and how to undo it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must have enabled the [*Snap tool*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/snapping.html#snapping) by mistake. To fix it, just click on the magnet at the top of the viewport, or press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>

[image: Snap tool]

Comment: :0 Thank you so much! That was it.